# Why does my tp-link router limit my cable connected pc's speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I got a new router "**A**" (modem integrated) from my *ISP* and I share my network over wireless to allow portable devices to access the internet. I would like to use my PC with a tp-link router ("**B**"). The router/modem **A** is in bridge mode so I can use my wifi router (**B**) too. If I connect my PC to router **A** (with cable), I can use the full speed that ISP provides.

If I connect my PC with a cable to router **B**, it limits me, but there is no limitation in the router's preferences. My router (**B**) supports 300 Mbs/s. I reset my router, but nothing happened with the bandwidth speed. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Limited in what way? Just a speed decrease? What speeds are you getting?  What speeds are you expected?  What speed is the NIC you're testing with?

Comment: *" If I connect my PC to router **A**, I can use the full speed that ISP provides"* -- Is this in bridge mode so that you have no firewall or NAT or any router functionality to slow the connection?

Comment: @techie007 I have a 120 mbs/s service and I can use the ~half of it with the tp-link router.

Comment: @sawdust It uses the full bandwidth also in bridge-mode and normal router mode too. The problem is with the **B** device.

Comment: *"The problem is with the B device."*  -- There are (wireless) router speed comparisons on the Web.  You apparently have one that cannot keep up with its WAN capabilities.